# How can I shrink images to fill screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website where I have made it so that the 4 pictures will be on the same line like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOB5W.png) but on smaller devices one of the pictures goes down a line. Is their a workaround that makes them all on the same line?

This is the html:

```
    <center>
    <h1>Meet Our Officers!</h1>
    <center>
    <div class="main">
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Adnan AL-Zoibi.jpg" width="275" height="300" alt="missing">
            <center><figcaption><h2>President</h2></figcaption></center>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Adnan AL-Zoibi.jpg" width="275" height="300" alt="missing">
            <center><figcaption><h2>Vice President</h2></figcaption></center>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Adnan AL-Zoibi.jpg" width="275" height="300" alt="missing">
            <center><figcaption><h2>Secertary</h2></figcaption></center>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="boysmeettheofficers/Adnan AL-Zoibi.jpg" width="275" height="300" alt="missing">
            <center><figcaption><h2>Treasurer</h2></figcaption></center>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are using bootstrap in your website then use class col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 and so on to make that the image has 1/4 if the size on every screen size

Answer (score 1):

column

```
.main {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }
```

line

```
.main {
    display:flex;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely! You should set the width of the figures to `width: 25%`

So with your extracted html I would do:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main figure {
  width: 25%;
}
```